PySpark optimization mindset - loop over groups with joins and union
I'm looping over groups in a PySpark dataframe and do one filter operation, several joins (depending on depth of group) and one union operation on each group. The individual groups are quite small, in my real-world use cases number of rows for each group ranges from 3-20. I have around 1500 groups to loop thru and it takes very long time.
I run this on Databricks 14.3, driver: 64 GB,8 workers.
I'm interested in how I should think in terms of optimization. There are lot of recommendations online - broadcasting, cache etc. But I found it hard to know when to use what and why.
How can the code snippet below be optimized? How would a Spark-developer think?
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("OPT").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "auto")

data = [
    ("A", 1, 0, 2121),
    ("A", 2, 2121, 5567),
    ("A", 3, 5567, 5566),
    ("A", 3, 5567, 5568),
    ("A", 3, 5567, 5569),
    ("A", 3, 5567, 5570),
    ("B", 1, 0, 3331),
    ("B", 2, 3331, 5515),
]
columns = ["group_id", "level", "parent", "node"]
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

test_df = test_df.withColumn("path", F.array("parent"))

# Create list to iterate over
list_to_iterate = test_df.groupBy("group_id").agg(F.max("level").alias("depth")).collect()

# Empty dataframe to store result from loop
new_result_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=test_df.schema)

for group in list_to_iterate:
    
    current_level = group['depth']
    tmp=test_df.filter(col('group_id')==group['group_id'])

    original_group = tmp

    while current_level > 1:
    
        # Repeatedly join operation 
        joined_df = tmp.alias("child").join(
            original_group.alias("parent"),
            F.col("child.parent") == F.col("parent.node"),
            "left" 
            ).select(
        F.col("child.group_id"),
        F.col("child.level"),
        F.col("parent.parent").alias("parent"),
        F.col("child.node"),
        # Append operation
        F.expr("CASE WHEN parent.parent IS NOT NULL THEN array_union(child.path, array(parent.parent)) ELSE child.path END").alias("path")
    )

        tmp = joined_df
        current_level -= 1

    # Union operation
    new_result_df = new_result_df.union(joined_df)


new_result_df.show(truncate=False)

Output:

+--------+-----+------+----+---------------+
|group_id|level|parent|node|path           |
+--------+-----+------+----+---------------+
|A       |1    |NULL  |2121|[0]            |
|A       |2    |NULL  |5567|[2121, 0]      |
|A       |3    |0     |5566|[5567, 2121, 0]|
|A       |3    |0     |5568|[5567, 2121, 0]|
|A       |3    |0     |5569|[5567, 2121, 0]|
|A       |3    |0     |5570|[5567, 2121, 0]|
|B       |1    |NULL  |3331|[0]            |
|B       |2    |0     |5515|[3331, 0]      |
+--------+-----+------+----+---------------+



Hey could you add the expected output?

@Jonathan - added output.

Your code will generate a query plan that will potentially include a large number of full shuffle operations. Have a look at this question to understand more about where these can occur:
What are the Spark transformations that causes a Shuffle?
It is sometimes possible to optimise queries by partitioning or clustering your data (CLUSTER BY is probably your best option here) but your data doesn't look like it would lend itself to that here. Using delta format over parquet can also help in some situations, but again, unless your data is very inefficiently stored, I'm not convinced that will be your issue.
Your data looks more like a graph data structure. I would look at the following question and answer, which demonstrates the use of GraphFrames - a library available in Databricks Runtime 14.3 LTS ML:
Spark: build recursive tree path for every node of an hierarchy DataFrame
